# using netty 4.1.9 for xml message processing

Tags: java, xml, netty

I am using netty 4.1.9 on a server receiving XML messages from a Netty client.  The client is able to send the xml message to the server.  However, on the server end, I need to be able to decode them as a single xml message (not a series of bytes).  I looked at xml frame decoder but could not figure out the best approach.  Would appreciate pointing in the right direction.

Initializer:

```
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        log.info("init channel called");
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        //add decoder for combining bytes for xml message
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new XmlMessageDecoder());

        // handler for business logic.
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new XmlServerHandler()); 
}
```

I was not able to use the xml frame decoder.  If I try to extend xml frame decoder in the mxl message decoder, I get the compilation error "there is no default constructor available in xmlframedecoder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the XmlFrameDecoder in my channel initializer and its output was passed to the handler where I was able to read the XML message from the ByteBuf.

**initializer**

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    // idle state handler
    pipeline.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(60,
            30, 0));
    pipeline.addLast("myHandler", new IdleHandler());

    //add decoder for combining bytes for xml message
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new XmlFrameDecoder(1048576));  

    // handler for business logic.
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerReceiverHandler()); 
}
```

**handler**

```
public class ServerReceiverHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        final ByteBuf buffer = (ByteBuf)msg;
        //prints out String representation of xml doc
        log.info("read : {}" + buffer.toString((CharsetUtil.UTF_8)));
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
    }
}
```